# static_initialization_and_destruction error on trying to compile a queue

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to implement a readerwriter queue.

My header file looks like this:

```
#ifndef CIRCULARSPSC_H
#define CIRCULARSPSC_H

#include <atomic>
#include <cstddef>

    template<typename Data, size_t Size> 
    class CircularSpsc
    {
    public:
        enum { queue_size = Size + 1 };

        CircularSpsc() : back(0), front(0){}
        virtual ~CircularSpsc() {}

        bool push_back(const Data& item);
        bool pop_front(Data& item);

        bool isEmpty() const;
        bool isFull() const;

    private:
        size_t increment(size_t idx) const;
        std::atomic<size_t> back;
        Data dataArray[queue_size];
        std::atomic<size_t> front;
    };


#endif
```

And this is my source file:

```
#include <circularspsc.h>


template<typename Data, size_t Size>
bool CircularSpsc<Data, Size>::push_back(const Data& item)
{   
    const auto current_back = back.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);

    const auto next_back = increment(current_back);
    if(next_back != front.load(std::memory_order_acquire))                           
    {   
        dataArray[current_back] = item;
        back.store(next_back, std::memory_order_release); 
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

template<typename Data, size_t Size>
bool CircularSpsc<Data, Size>::pop_front(Data& item)
{
    const auto currentfront = front.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
    if(currentfront == back.load(std::memory_order_acquire))
        return false;

    item = dataArray[currentfront];
    front.store(increment(currentfront), std::memory_order_release);
    return true;
}

template<typename Data, size_t Size>
bool CircularSpsc<Data, Size>::isEmpty() const
{
    return (front.load() == back.load());
}

template<typename Data, size_t Size>
bool CircularSpsc<Data, Size>::isFull() const
{
    const auto nextback = increment(back.load());
    return (nextback == front.load());
}

template<typename Data, size_t Size>
size_t CircularSpsc<Data, Size>::increment(size_t idx) const
{
    return (idx + 1) % queue_size;
}
```

In my main file when I try to create an instance of the queue implemented above like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "circularspsc.h"

int main()
{
    CircularSpsc<bool, 100000> cspsc_q;

}
```

I am getting the following errors:

```
    /tmp/ccQFNFP5.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
main.cpp:(.text+0x53): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x62): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
/tmp/ccQFNFP5.o: In function `circular_spsc_relaxed::CircularSpsc<bool, 100000ul>::~CircularSpsc()':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN21circular_spsc_relaxed12CircularSpscIbLm100000EED0Ev[_ZN21circular_spsc_relaxed12CircularSpscIbLm100000EED5Ev]+0x20): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)'
/tmp/ccQFNFP5.o:(.rodata._ZTIN21circular_spsc_relaxed12CircularSpscIbLm100000EEE[_ZTIN21circular_spsc_relaxed12CircularSpscIbLm100000EEE]+0x0): undefined reference to `vtable for __cxxabiv1::__class_type_info'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

If I remove the virtual destructor from my queue implementation, I still get the following two errors:

```
`__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
    main.cpp:(.text+0x53): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
    main.cpp:(.text+0x62): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
```

I am compiling with:

`gcc -std=c++11 -o testQueue circularspsc.cpp main.cpp`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to compile with g++ not gcc

Comment: Lol I cannot believe myself sometimes. Thank you so much. Now that you are here, can you do a small code review for my queue. Its not homework I promise.

Comment: @Chani If your code compiles, and you're looking for a code review, a post over on [codereview.SE] would be appropriate.